# No realiza ninguna acción php artisan queue:work

Tags: php, laravel, queue

Cordial saludo,

Estoy tratando de implementar el envío de correo electrónico una vez se cree un usuario desde la aplicación. Implementé el tema de los queues con un Job, sin embargo, cuando ejecuto en la consola php artisan queue:work e intento crear un usuario efectivamente envío el correo electrónico pero un poco demorado y en la consola no pasa nada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias, espero su cordial ayuda.

Comment: Fijate que en tu archivo .env no tengas las colas configuradas como sincronas que es el valor por defecto.

Comment: Agrega tu código, no somos adivinos. Si agregaste el job a una cola con nombre personalizado, debes agregar ````--queue=my_queue```` a tu comando. Asegúrate de tener correctamente configurado los drivers y desde luego, un servidor de correos o un SMTP funcional (Puedes usar el de google para probar).
Mira los logs de laravel para ver si hay algún error, si lo hay, ponlo en la publicación.